# How to automatically fill page-number in page reference with office 2013 Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I make a lot of documents with Office Word and because I know I've to do a lot more I'm always trying to make my work more efficient.

Now there is a feature in Word which let me make an automatic table of contents. Which will look like this:

[image]

The page-numbers are automatically filled in based on the position of the document headers. So if Word is that smart I asked myself is there a way to let wordt automatically fill a page-number when I make a page reference inside my document like:

```
For more information on this see page {autofill from header:Call details}
```

Does someone knows if there is a feature for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft Word has a very well known and popular feature to achieve this called Cross references. For details of how to insert a cross reference you can refer to [this](http://www.lse.ac.uk/intranet/LSEServices/IMT/guides/softwareGuides/office2010/Word-2010-Reference.aspx) page for example.

Comment: Ah this looks like it I shall try this